# Error when using JSON derived data in Tensorflow

Tags: json, tensorflow

I'm using the following code, derived from the documentation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('/root/ml/2017110508.training.json') as text:
    data = json.load(text)
    features = np.array(data['input']['values'])
    labels = np.array(data['output']['values'])
    pprint(features.shape)
    pprint(labels.shape)
    pprint(features[0:3])
    pprint(labels[0:3])

# Assume that each row of `features` corresponds to the same row as `labels`.
assert features.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```

The data in data['input']['values'] and data['output']['values'] are simply rows of floats but I get:

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [0.6, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0,
>   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.5, 0.0, 0.4, 7.7, -8.5, 158.0, 6.2, 55.3, 203.4, 205.7, 156.5, -8.5, 7.3, -8.8, 53.5, -0.9, -31.2, 15.3, -1.9, -87.6, 21.3, -21.6, -34.7, -17.1, -85.0, 28.6, -19.1]

What format is **from_tensor_slices** expecting?

Thanks.

Output from the **pprint** calls:

> (58502,)
>
> (58502, 5)
>
> array([ list([0.6, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.6, 1.5, 0.0,
>   0.4, 7.7, -8.5, 158.0, 6.2, 55.3, 203.4, 205.7, 156.5, -8.5, 7.3, -8.8, 53.5, -0.9, -31.2, 15.3, -1.9, -87.6, 21.3, -21.6, -34.7, -17.1, -85.0, 28.6, -19.1]),
>          list([1.3, 0.0, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 1.0, 2.3, 0.0, 0.6, 7.7, -8.5, 158.0, 6.2, 55.3, 203.4, 205.7, 156.4, -8.5, 7.5, -8.8, 53.4, -0.9, -31.2, 15.3, -1.9, -87.6, 21.3, -21.6, -34.7, -17.0, -85.0, 28.6, -19.1]),
>          list([2.0, 0.0, 1.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 1.1, 2.9, 0.0, 0.9, 8.0, -8.5, 158.2, 6.2, 55.3, 203.4, 205.7, 156.3, -8.5, 8.0, -8.8, 53.3, -0.9, -31.2, 15.1, -1.9, -87.6, 21.3, -21.6, -34.8, -16.8, -84.9, 28.6, -19.1])], dtype=object)
>
> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

Comment: Can you add the output of `features.shape`, `labels.shape`, and the first few rows of each?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I updated the post above with answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is actually in your JSON file.  The output of your `labels` variable is good; the output of your `features` variable should have the same structure, but instead it has `list` in there a bunch of times.  If your JSON file has "list" showing up several times as an attribute you should delete those along with their round brackets (and possibly some extra square brackets).  If you generated the JSON yourself then it's probably easier to make the change there.

An unrelated issue is that your labels are all 0; if this isn't what you were expecting then you probably lost some data somewhere.